# XML-RPC calls in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-rpc

I am trying to using wordpress xml-rpc on windows phone 7 but can't find any API's for making rpc calls. Does anyone know of any libraries or a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [XML-RPC.NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) which is a free library. Once you download the bundle, there is a CF (Compact Framework) version of the DLL - due to platform restrictions, you have to use this version.

Note, however, that (quote from the documentation):

> 6.11 Does XML-RPC.NET work with .Net Compact Framework?
>
> The XML-RPC.NET distribution contains
>   an assembly which provides support for
>   the .NET Compact Framework:
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.CF.dll. Note that
>   this is an experimental version and is
>   mostly untested. Also, because the
>   Compact Framework does not support
>   reflection it is necessary to
>   implement XML-RPC.NET proxies manully.

Comment: instigator, did you have any luck using the library?

Comment: i tried it. Doesn't work. it shows the following error when trying to convert. i'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.

The project file '...\xml-rpc.net.2.5.0\xmlrpcCF\xmlrpcCF.csproj' cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation.

Answer (score 1):

The XML-RPC.NET library version 3.0 is now compatible with Windows Phone 7 projects.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `XmlRpcProxyGen` class? Because it says it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

I believe `XmlRpcProxyGen` doesn't exist in the Windows Phone library as the platform doesn't support the `System.Reflection` classes.